# to delete two or more elements one time

Tags: r

I want to delete elements the first and the sixth in a vector,
is there better  way to do so?

```
> x=c(4,42,232,4,55,74,45)
> x=x[-1]
> x=x[-5]
> x
[1] 42 232 4 55  45
```

can i  delete them one time,not two times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- c(4,42,232,4,55,74,45)
x <- x[-c(1,5)]
x

[1]  42 232   4  74  45
```